# Como se pode fazer uma tabela automatica , com organização e "paginação" em android?

Tags: android

Preciso de fazer uma tabela de dados com cerca de 5 a 6 colunas, com dados de multiplos arrays.
O objectivo é poder ter o mais parecido possivel a uma tabela de gestão onde o utilizador pode organizar a tabela por nome , por id e por ai vai e tem que ter paginação para evitar que seja uma tabela muito grande.

Primeira questão qual o design mais indicado para se fazer? temdo em conta que sao 5 a 6 colunas com dados com nomes extensos.

Outra pergunta é como se gera automaticamente a tabela e se faz a "paginação" e organização por nome, id  etc.

Exemplo de uma tabela que fiz em html e php o objectivo era ter algo parecido no android :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ok, e como seria no Android? Há diversas formas de fazer no Android. Talvez o que procura pode ser apenas "javascript grid table".. Pesquise por isso para ter uma ideia.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize um recyclerView e crie um layout para a linha e outro para o cabeçalho(este deve ser chamado quando a posicão retornar 0)

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543131/how-to-implement-endless-list-with-recyclerview) tem um exemplo de paginação.

Formas possíveis de organizar:

- Ao selecionar uma linha você exibe as opções "x" e "?" na toolbar.
- Use ícones para a coluna estado
- IDParagem pode virar ID
- Você pode pensar em um uso para o `Float Action Button`
- Caso a linha seja sempre uma cor você pode usar um textView que teria a cor da linha com um número nesta cor.

.